# My follower won't pick up items

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, nintendo-switch

My follower won't pick up items in the Nintendo Switch edition of Skyrim.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any customized controllers, particularly the activate command? If so, [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/ccmx40/companions_wont_pick_up_items_nintendo_switch/ett4flb/) thread mentions this might be a bug on the Switch version of Skyrim. Followers do not seem to pick up items unless the activate command is the default configuration, that being the A button.

Try resetting your activate command to be the default. A user on the reddit thread confirmed this was a solution for them.